How could an Underground city be ventilated?
Normally, human activity produces heat and therefore, an underground city would have to ventilate and facilitate air flow.
What are some ways in which this could be possible?
Details about the setting:
Technology is fairly advanced
The world is earth-like, but not necessarily the same.
The City is about as deep as the Veryovkina Cave in Russia.
Living organisms are all made up basically. If a solution involves creating a certain plant, animal or mushroom to do the job that is okay.
Magic is not a thing in this world.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome user. It would be very helpful if you were to tell us what you've considered and why you discarded it, this would narrow the issues down to a potential "best answer". You should use the [edit] button to tell us why wind/thermal gradients are not sufficient and if not, then why? You might need to specify the biomass and the dimensions of the cave too.

That comment from the automated Community BOT is a red flag that means your question fails Stack Exchange's basic metrics for a good question. Here's some reasons why: Per the [help/on-topic], brainstorming is discouraged, per the [help/dont-ask] open-ended questions are prohibited and per the [tour] we're not a discussion forum. We answer specific questions that can have an objectively selected best answer. Per the [ask] page, you're expected to perform research.
So, what research have you done and how will you select a best answer?

I think this one may have been asked before? I'll have a look for it later.

Might I point the OP towards some real-world underground-cities for research purposes.

You haven't provided a lot of the details needed to answer this question properly. Most importantly? Why does the atmosphere of the city need to be self contained and why? Also is the atmosphere on the surface breathable and is the surface in general 'Earth like'. What is 'threat/problem?

Aside from the lack of details, you state magic is not a thing in your world, then tag the question as magic. Which one is it?

@L.Dutch I apologize, the tag must have been a mistake, I do not remember adding the tag magic.

@JBH I'm sorry. I discovered this site about a week ago and I'm very new as to how should I word my questions as well as how much detail I must add. I will consider this for future questions. Thanks for the feedback

@Pica The edit makes the question substantially broader, so much so that it won't get reopened. Are you sure you meant to do that?

I wanted to offer the user a buffet to pick from and then put the plate at the checkout. Also sometimes writting down the "No, i actually ment"- brings forth the real question

@Pica You made the question worse. How could this be technologically acomplished without running into the problems we have with todays mines and underground facilities? Anybody who could reasonably answer that would be running for the patent office, not answering here. And "offer[ing] the user a buffet to pick from" violates Stack Exchange's rules. Remember SE's rules about editing, you're NOT allowed to change the OP's intent. I'm recommending the Mods revert th edit and next time, ask the OP for permission first.

@JBH Common misconception that a idea is worth something. Ideas are completely worthless and aplenty. Realized solutions are worth something and a basis for going to the patent office. OPs post was on the block anyway- and he was to become one of the nameless who give up on SO after theire questions go nowhere. I wanted to be constructive instead of destructive for the site.

@Pica You can't be constructive by destroying other people's questions. Try engaging with the OP.

@Pica I wouldn't say I have given up. If anything, the comments of these posts have made me realize that there is still a lot of details and points I need to research on. My idea is indeed very vague. Hopefully I will be able to formulate better questions in the future that meet the guidelines of the site (since I'm still new). I appreciate the feedback

@JBH I appreciate what you have said, but don't worry. Yes, the editing might have been done without consent but I don't mind at this point, I recognize that my original question wasn't very good either. I am starting to get an idea of how things have to be done, but for that I need to fail a couple times  I'll keep up with my research and hopefully I'll get it right in the future. Thanks for all the feedback you have provided btw! I have seen you in the 2 posts I have made so far. Thanks again

Since the other post is 8yrs old, and is also poorly worded to make it seem like this is a different question (yet can't be answered)
Heat:
A column of warm air, rising, would pull from any tunnels at the bottom, cooler, fresh air. Its used in some Mediterranean houses, known as thermal chimneys, thermosiphons, or thermosyphons.

@BaneStar007 this is really helpful, I'll look more into it. Thank you!!
